# How to update a React HOC prior to HOC executing componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a React component that is wrapped in a HOC. The HOC establishes a subscription within `componentDidMount` that causes the HOC to rerender whenever the HOC's `setState` function is called, which rerenders the wrapped component. This is similar to how Redux Connect works.

The issue I have is the wrapped component (child) is responsible for providing the data that HOC, which the requires to establish the subscriptions. It comes from the props passed into the child.

I can see from the console that `componentDidMount` is not called from the HOC until the wrapped (child) components `componentDidMount` is executed.

Would it be acceptable to create a handler method that allows the wrapped component to update the class properties of the HOC using `this.data = data`?

This would allow the HOC to use the data from the wrapped component in order to setup the subscription.

**HOC**

```
const HOCComponent= function HOCComponent(config) {
  return function returnWrapped(Wrapped) {
    return class Wrapper extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this)
        this.data = {}
      }

      comonentDidMount() {
        setSubscription(this.data, () => {
          this.setState({
            key: getData(),
          })
        })
      }

      handleData(data) {
        this.data = data
      }
      render () {
        <Wrapped handleData={this.handleData} /> 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**CHILD**

```
const Component class Wrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // Stuff        
    props.handleData(props.data)
  }
  render() {
    <div>Hello!</div>
  }
}
```

In the above, `props.handleData` could also be called from within the `componentDidMount` of the child.

Comment: Do you mean to find a way to update the data in the HOC from the child component? And It's better that you have example code.

Comment: Yes, we want to update the data in the HOC prior to the HOC's componentDidMount method being called.

Comment: -- so that the subscriptions created by the HOC use the data from the child

Comment: I think the right way is that the child doesn't update the data itself. But it call the callback to the HOC to update the data on the HOC. Then from the HOC, It can send data to all of the subscriptions. Does I understand your problem correctly?

Comment: After read your code example. I think that the solution should be: Instead of try to make the method called before componentDidMount, we still let it called like the above example. But in the render method, we will check if the data is loaded or not. If It's not loaded, render "null", otherwise `render` the rest.